# Оптимизация php кода.

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте.

Есть код:

```
// GetUsers
$uConnect2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
while($uInfo2 = mysql_fetch_array($uConnect2)) {
 $resp2 = $VK->api('users.get', array('uid' => $uInfo2[uid], 'fields' => 'photo_medium'));

 $getUserAva = $resp2[response][0][photo_medium];
 $getUserID = $resp2[response][0][uid];
 $getUserName = $resp2[response][0][first_name];
 $getUserSurname = $resp2[response][0][last_name];
 $rand_users .= "
   <div class=\"vote_bg\" id=\"user$getUserID\">
    <div class=\"vote_ava\">
     <div class=\"vote_name\">$getUserName $getUserSurname</div>
     <div align=\"center\">
      <img src=\"$getUserAva\">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id=\"voteBtn$getUserID\">
     <div class=\"button_blue button_wide vote_btn\"><button class=\"load_b$getUserID\" id=\"button2\" onclick=\"vote.plus($getUserID)\">Проголосовать</button></div>
    </div>
    <div id=\"voteOK$getUserID\" class=\"vote_ok\">Ваш голос учтён!</div>
   </div>";
}
```

Так вот, как оптимизировать его, то есть $resp2 = $VK->api ... коннектит 4 раза, так как он в цикле и порой получается сбой.

Помогите, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно документации ВКонтакте API можно передавать массив с ID пользователей, которые необходимо вернуть... точнее... не более какого-то числа.

А так, дайте угадаю, скорее всего, каждый 5-й пользователь у Вас не отрабатывает, угадал, да ?:)

Рассмотрим эту страницу: [users.get](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=users.get). Первое, что в глаза бросилось относительно users.get:

> `uids - перечисленные через запятую ID пользователей или их короткие имена (screen_name). Максимум 1000 пользователей.`

Теперь посмотрите на Ваш метод: нет, Вы не получаете строку с id через запятую. Вы делаете отдельный запрос по каждому пользователю.

Answer (score 2):

В [документации](http://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=users.get) описан метод users.get с параметром uids (перечисленные через запятую ID пользователей), используйте его.

```
$uids = '';
while($uInfo2 = mysql_fetch_array($uConnect2)) {
    $uids .= ','.$uInfo2[uid];
}
$uids = substr($uids, 1); //убираем первую запятую

$resp2 = $VK->api('users.get', array('uids' => $uids, 'fields' => 'photo_medium'));
foreach ($resp2[response] as $vk_user) {
    //выводим результат
}
```